# HasPublishedVersion property using CSOM C#

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, csom, list-item, version

I am using SharePoint C# CSOM to get items from the SharePoint 2010 site Document Library.

I need to check if the item has any published version. 
In SSOM we have to  Property  called  **HasPublishedVersion** to check for the  **SPListItem**.

Is there any similar column that I can use in CSOM c#? or is there any way I can check for published version in CSOM C#?

Can anyone help me on this..?

Answer (score 0):

CSOM ListItem not porovide similiar property like HasPublishedVersion in SSOM:

[ListItem members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee544534(v%3Doffice.15))

A workaround is that creating a web service with SPListItem.HasPublishedVersion and then call the web service from Client Side with JavaScript or add web reference in Visual Studio:

[How to create an ASMX web service on sharepoint 2010 Using VS2010](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-to-create-an-asmx-web-service-on-sharepoint-using-vs)